# android studio palette is not visible in my activity.xml whereas it can be seen in my android emulator

Tags: android-studio

Android studio palette is not visible in my activity . xml whereas it can be seen in my android emulator

[image: Emulator]

Comment: show your xml file

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
Window -> Restore Default Layout (Shift+F12)
```

Comment: sorry but its still not working .....the components can be seen in the emulator but it is not shown when i drag and drop it from palette to my xml file